# debugging and intellisensing pyramid application

Tags: python, debugging, intellisense, pyramid

There is a wonderful video on youtube where it is explained how to debug Django applications with Python Tools for Visual Studio.

I wonder if the same thing is possible with the Pyramid applications? Moreover I would love to use VS' IntelliSense (hinting system) while writing for the Pyramid framework.
Or may be there are another ways to achieve the same debug+IntelliSense effect. I'd be glad to hear any suggestions.

Comment: A link to the wonderful video would help :) But generally - they both Python, the procedure should be similar

Answer (score 2):

To my mind there's two viable option out there.

I use both actually.

### Eclipse + Aptana Studio + Pydev or Aptana Studio

Pros

1. Free
2. Decent auto completion (IntelliSense like system)
3. More plug-ins (since it's based on eclipse)
4. Support django template
   Cons
5. relatively poor html editor
6. no mako or jinja2 support (as far as I know)

### Pycharm

Pros

1. better auto completion
2. Support mako,jinja2 and django template
3. Good HTML edtitor

Cons

1. Not Free

Both support debug without too many problems.

Comment: Hummm... actually, if you're in Aptana Studio 3, you do have django templates support. As for the html editor, what are you expecting which is missing?

Comment: Sorry @FabioZadrozny I edited it. and Thank you visiting my answer post :) I really love pydev! but I really want pydev support jinja2 template engine.

Comment: Awesome -- I use PHPStorm for php coding and highly prefer it over Aptana... I didn't realize JetBrains has something for Python :)